# UnsupportedOperationException in Wildfly 9.0.1.Final

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8, myfaces

I am running my code on Latest Wildfly 9.0.1.Final(JBoss).
During deployment I am facing lot of issues and deployment is marked as faild.
Below is my server.log

```
ERROR [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262) Error initializing ServletContext: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.application.Application.addELContextListener(Application.java:1427)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplication.<init>(WeldApplication.java:56)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplicationFactory.getApplication(WeldApplicationFactory.java:52)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configureApplication(FacesConfigurator.java:568)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:148)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.initFaces(StartupServletContextListener.java:68)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:51)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,506 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262) java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

2015-09-04 11:46:13,506 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at javax.faces.application.Application.addELContextListener(Application.java:1427)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,506 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplication.<init>(WeldApplication.java:56)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,506 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplicationFactory.getApplication(WeldApplicationFactory.java:52)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,506 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configureApplication(FacesConfigurator.java:568)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,506 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:148)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.initFaces(StartupServletContextListener.java:68)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:51)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262)   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

2015-09-04 11:46:13,522 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262) ServletContext 'E:\Mahendra\FDMS\FDMS Software\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment\deployment4b98e9eab26d7135\WEBFDMSDashboard.war-490d541171eb43e' initialized.
2015-09-04 11:46:13,537 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.11-jbossorg-1 20150505-1501 for context '/dashboard'
2015-09-04 11:46:17,438 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 272) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /webservicesfdms
2015-09-04 11:46:17,548 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Creating Service {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wsat}WSATCoordinator from WSDL: WEB-INF/wsdl/wsat.wsdl
2015-09-04 11:46:18,919 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262) Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2015-09-04 11:46:18,997 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:330)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:404)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:248)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:529)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:275)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.application.Application.addELContextListener(Application.java:1427)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplication.<init>(WeldApplication.java:56)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplicationFactory.getApplication(WeldApplicationFactory.java:52)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:144)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:402)
    ... 17 more

2015-09-04 11:46:18,997 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 262) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./dashboard: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./dashboard: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:224)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:330)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:404)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:248)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:529)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:275)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.application.Application.addELContextListener(Application.java:1427)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplication.<init>(WeldApplication.java:56)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplicationFactory.getApplication(WeldApplicationFactory.java:52)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:144)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:402)
    ... 17 more
```

Please help me resolve this issues.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WildFly contains the JSF reference implementation Mojarra. You seem to be using MyFaces, presumably embedded in your JAR. This does not work out of the box.

See [this article](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DesignOfWildFlyMulti-JSFFeature) on using other JSF implementations with WildFly.

Comment: Does following those steps will help me to get resolve these errors ?

Comment: running "build" script is taking too long to download dependencies.

Comment: I always receive an error "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project wildfly-ts-integ-web: There are test failures."

Comment: I also get "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (ban-transitive-deps) on project wildfly-feature-pack: Some Enforcer rules have failed."

Comment: I also get "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-java-version) on project wildfly-parent: Some Enforcer rules have failed."

Comment: I have source release of 9.0.1.Final